# Excel VBA: How to use objects defined in a previous module in a new module without defining them again

Tags: vba, excel

I have previously defined `Report_wb` in an module `Obtain_Data`, and now I am writing a new module `Module1`. I want to use the object `Report_wb` without defining it again. Is there any way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: If you make `Report_wb` public, then you can reference it in other modules as `Obtain_Data.Report_wb`.

Answer (score 0):

rather than declaring Report_wb as a dim within a sub, write it as a public declaration at the top of the module

i.e.

```
'Module 1

Public stringTest as string

Sub SetString()
stringTest = "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

and then in another module:

```
'Module 2

Sub TestString()
call SetString
debug.print stringTest
End Sub
```

Comment: the `Call` is not necessary.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `Call` isn't required, but it may be used as a style preference by the author.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie syntactic sugar that has no impact on the purpose or functionality of the example.